# How to set Date and Time intervals in UIPicker.DatePicker Mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, uidatepicker, nscalendar

I like to restrict my datetime picker with some restriction.

Before tell my requirements please refer my code:

```
datepicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
    datepicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
    datepicker.minimumDate=[NSDate date];
    [datepicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [_txtDateTime setInputView:datepicker];
```

i know its basic of date and time picker controller.

But what i need is from current date to +15 days only have to display and time should be 8:00am to 10.00pm only have to display.

Show me the way to achieve it ,thanks :).

Comment: As you can see from the documentation, `UIDatePicker` doesn't provide such functionality. Use `UIPickerView` instead.

Comment: ok i will try with UIPickerView bro @A-Live

Comment: then what is the use of minimum and maximun date @A-Live , i have doubt in this section

Comment: Sometimes you want to let only chose time in the future, only from this week, only from the past month. These values don't affect the intervals between available options, only the options range.

Comment: @A-Live see the below answer logic but its doesn't work :( . so now i am decide to give uialerviewcontroller if its exist my requirement .

Comment: `UIPickerView`, not `UIAlertController` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find out the date after 15 days and add it as max date
need to check for time, 
for calculating days

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateformate=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

[dateformate setDateFormat:kDateFormat];
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDate *Daysafter = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:15*24*60*60];
```

For time also i think you can directly set min and max also

Comment: Daysafter is your date which you need to set as max date to picker in same way you set minimum
 
    [datePicker setMaximumDate:Daysafter];

Comment: and kDateFormat is format you want to use suppose
@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
@kishore plz upvote the answer if it helps you

Comment: i sets maximum and minimum even though its scrolling above 15 days from current date ,and getting back from now a day .

Comment: datePicker= [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
    [datePicker setAlpha:1];
    [datePicker addTarget:self action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    [datePicker setMinimumDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSDateFormatter *dateformate=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateformate setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *Daysafter = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:15*24*60*60];
    [datePicker setMaximumDate:Daysafter];
Its working perfectly i created it by myself

Comment: datepicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
    datepicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *Daysafter =[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:15*24*60*60 sinceDate:now];
    datepicker.minimumDate=now;
    datepicker.maximumDate=Daysafter;
    [datepicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [_txtDateTime setInputView:datepicker];

Comment: your code is also working man
datePicker= [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *Daysafter =[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:15*24*60*60 sinceDate:now];
    datePicker.minimumDate=now;
    datePicker.maximumDate=Daysafter;
    [self.view addSubview:datePicker];
see i use that in mine and its get scroll upto 19feb only

Comment: might be you get confused picker will defiantly going to scroll above 15 days but it will not take dates if you tried to set to label or something, which are above the 15 days, and whenever you scroll up-to 15 days then only it will be stick to those dates, that is default behavior of picker.

Comment: if i use dateandtimepicker its didn't work ,and also i changed this to datepicker but my expectation is ,if todays date is 1 then i like to display from 1 to 15 days not 15+15+!5.

Comment: yeah that's what the code did, and that is why i told you that if you try to pick date from picker it will allow you onl;y upto 19feb, and 19feb is the date after 15 days right as current date 4feb

Comment: thats not a problem bro but your code is display 19 feb then march y.

Comment: thats default behavior bro, the thing is that it will allow to 19feb only

Comment: my expectation is 1.2.2016 to 15.2.2016 upto only it have to display.

Comment: then you need to creates all dates and create a array of that dates and use that array as data source  for custom picker

Comment: yes its my mistake you code works but time having problem.

Comment: what is the problem with time

Comment: 8 am to 10 pm only i have to display is there any way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102601/discussion-between-kishore-kumar-and-vijay-palwe).

Comment: shall we start discuss in chat.